# How to use Excel Rank Formula as a specific type?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, match, rank

I want to use a formula the first value (4) will have a rank of 1, the Second value (3) will have a rank of 2, The Third value (3) will have a rank of 2, and the fourth value (2) will have a rank of 3. Ex: 4,3,3,2 will as Rank 1,2,2,3

please Help

I want it's solution

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=XMATCH(A1:A4,SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A4),,-1))
```

Comment: I will just add `TOCOL()` to refer full column if OP has long dataset and if there any possibility to grow later. `=XMATCH(TOCOL(A:A,1),SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),,-1))`.